# If we don't reference to a non initialized variable will it still allocate memory from it's default value?

Tags: java

My question is in regards of memory with non initialized variables.

Lets say we reference to `a` field like this:

```
class JustAClass {
     static int a;

     public static void main(String[] args){
         System.out.println(a);
     }
}
```

Now in the above example the variable `a` will be by default assigned a value of 0(which will acquire memory in RAM) and 0 will be printed in the console.

However what if we didn't make a reference to the a variable and simply ran the program like this:

```
class JustAClass {
     static int a;

     public static void main(String[] args){
        
     }
}
```

Would `a` still acquire memory in this case?

Comment: Yes, it would. Some outside source (e.g. if we package our code in a `jar` and that `jar` is used by some other java program) could try to write/read that variable (e.g. through the means of reflection).

Comment: And what about non initialized local variables without any references? I assume that they woudn't take any memory since local variables don't have any default values but they nonetheless can be declared without initialization, atleast if we don't make a reference to them or else an error occurs.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: @Turing85 It would be quite inefficient to make useless posts about very relatable questions.

Comment: The questions are not "relatable" at all. A field is quite different from a local variable. One resides on the heap, the other on the stack.

Comment: @Turing85 They actually are very relatable because the initial question was about fields wich are "relatable" to local variables and i asked about the same thing about them both wich is whether or not the variables in their non initialized form still consume memory. And whether "one resides on the heap and the other on the stack is of none importance" is really not of importance about the relatability about both questions.

Comment: @syclone Are you talking about variables or fields in your question? It looks like you are talking about fields, but in the question you are talking about variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as it might be accessed in non trivial way which static compiler cannot detect - like using reflection.

Comment: However would a initialized local variable without references also occupy memory even if that method where that variable is not invoked?

Comment: @user16320675 any direct call would be a "trivial" which could be statically detected in tree-shaking fashion, thus I wrote that only as an example.

Comment: @syclone loacl var is a different story as it has a scope of "block" and becomes GColectable when execution quits the block (unles leaked obviosuly) . It is possible that it might be gone from the bytecode

Comment: Not realy as you never have the guarantee it is the "all of the code" ;) Block vars on the other hand, might be ;) There is not notion of "all sources" as it always can be extended somehow.